# Would someone mind proving this: For all odd primes $p$, $-1\in QR_p \iff p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

The proof my textbook gives doesn't make much sense to me.

It says,

$-1 \in QR_p \iff -1^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, then says

If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $(-1)^{(p-1)/2} \equiv -1 \neq 1 \pmod p$.

But if $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $(-1)^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

I'm not sure about those last two lines, why "If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $(-1)^{(p-1)/2} \equiv -1 \neq 1 \pmod p$"?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know Euler's criterion?

Answer (score 1):

If $p \equiv 3$ write $p=4k+3,$ then $p-1=4k+2, \ (p-1)/2=2k+1$ is odd, so raising $(-1)$ to that power gives $-1.$ The other case is similar.

Comment: Didn't think of that.  Thanks! Clears it up.

Comment: Yes it isn't difficult once you put things into $4k+1$ or $4k+3$ format. (I'm assuming you had no problem applying Gauss' Lemma (or is that Euler's criterion? -- saw Pedro's comment) that the residue symbol $(a|p)$ is congruent mod $p$ to $a^{(p-1)/2}.$